# How to set the content view of a Activity from another actvity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am building an music player. Whenever the user will click on a `ImageView`, a dialog will come. The dialog will have a switch in it. I wanted to say that whenever the user switches on the switch to on, I wanted to change the `ContentView` of `MainActivity.java`  to a custom layout file. How can I do that.

Any suggestions would be accepted..
Thanks

Comment: Do you want the dialog to remain visible, and the content to change behind the dialog?

Comment: Yes @CarsonHolzheimer

Comment: I have added an answer , please mark it right if it is something you were looking for , in case you find any difficulty you can add the comment below my answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a callback to your Dialog that you simply invoke to set your content, something like

```
class MyDialog(val switchChangedCallback: (Boolean) -> Unit) : DialogFragment() ...
```

When you change the switch, invoke the callback and handle the result in the Activity:

```
val dialog = MyDialog(switchChangedCallback = { isOn ->
                if (isOn) {
                    setContentView(R.layout.abc)
                } else {
                    setContentView(R.layout.def)
                }
            })

dialog.show(supportFragmentManager, MyDialog::class.java.name)
```

You may need to check that the callback survives app rotation!

Answer (score 0):

You can try `below code`...

Dialogue :

```html
Dialog dialogue = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialogue.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialogue.setCancelable(false);
        dialogue.setContentView(R.layout.dialogue);

        Switch mySwitch = (Switch) dialogue.findViewById(R.id.MYSWITCH);
        Button btnClose = (Button) dialogue.findViewById(R.id.CLOSEBTN);


        mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if(isChecked){
                    setContentView(R.layout.layout1);
                }
                else{
                    setContentView(R.layout.layout2);
                }
            }
        });

        btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialogue.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialogue.show();
```

**dialogue.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/MYSWITCH"
        android:text="Change Layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/CLOSEBTN"
        android:text="Close"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

as your question says you **need a switch inside dialogue** , so we need to create a **custom dialogue layout** and apply it to dialogue !